# Not to propagate the maven build number when merging?

Tags: git, maven, merge, pom.xml

I have updated my pom.xml to create the final name of the build such

```xml
<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${buildNumber}</finalName>
```

where the build number is taken from the property

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>    
    <buildNumber>${project.artifactId}-${maven.build.timestamp}</buildNumber>
</properties>
```

This works perfectly, but what I want is that when I merge this branch to another branch, the final name stays the same. Instead, in this way, after I merge and compile the timestamp at the compilation is appended to the final name of the build on the final branch.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Didn't get - you want the build information from your feature branch to propagate to the merged branch? Then you'd have to hardcode the value in the `pom.xml`. But overall the idea seems mm.. unusual :)

Comment: Yes it is unusual :), but we thought that if we merge our staging branch with prod branch, the two versions must be the same because we don't make any changes. If we tag the prod branch with the timestamp, it seems we have two different versions on staging and prod. If you have any suggestion how to do differently, I would appreciate.

Comment: Every time someone wants to build & deploy from branches - this causes a lot of headache. I can get deployment to some personal envs or to performance env - somewhere where we just experiment. But deploying to DEV/TST/Staging from a branch seems like an overcomplication. If you follow CI, you probably want to push to master, and _then_ deploy to all shared envs from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am interpreting your question as:

- on branch `prod`, the build number should not change if another branch has already produced an artifact with said build number. Which means main would reuse the one from `staging`, if said `staging` branch did produce such a build number.
- on other branches (from which you would merge to `main`/`prod`), the build number remains as it is now: dynamically generated on each build.

I talk about artifact because, [in Maven, `finalName` is a configuration element within the `<build>` section of the `pom.xml` that defines the filename](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html) (without the file extension) of the generated artifact in the `target` directory.

When Maven builds a project, it generates an artifact (e.g., JAR, WAR, EAR, etc.) and places it in the `target` directory of the project. The name of this artifact can be customized with a `finalName` configuration.

To make sure that the artifact's name (specifically, the timestamp within the name) remains unchanged when merging the `staging` branch to the `prod` branch, you will need to find a way to "carry over" the timestamp from the `staging` artifact to the `prod` build.

You would need to:

- capture the timestamp from the `staging` artifact during the build: When building on the `staging` branch, capture the generated timestamp and store it in a file (let's say `timestamp.txt`) within the source directory. That file will be committed to the repository.

_ use this timestamp during the `prod` build: When building on the `prod` branch (after merging from `staging`), read the timestamp from the `timestamp.txt` file and use it as the `buildNumber`.

You can conditionally set the build number based on the branch being built, using Maven profiles:

- Define two profiles in your `pom.xml`:

  - one (named "`non-prod`") for your `feature`/`development`/`staging` branches and
  - another (named "`prod`") for your `main`/`prod` branch.
- In the `non-prod` branch profile, set the build number as you currently have it.
- In the `prod` branch profile, set the build number to the value retrieved from `timestamp.txt`

---

In the `non-prod` profile:

- Use the [`maven-antrun-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to write the current timestamp to a file.
- Commit this file as part of your changes in the `staging` branch.

```xml
<profile>
    <id>staging</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <!-- Write the current timestamp to a file -->
                                <echo file="timestamp.txt">${maven.build.timestamp}</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

---

In the `prod` profile:

- Use the [`maven-antrun-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to read the timestamp from the `timestamp.txt` file and set it to a property.
- Use this property as your `buildNumber`.

```xml
<profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <!-- Read the timestamp from the file and set to a property -->
                                <loadfile property="loaded.timestamp" srcFile="timestamp.txt"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <buildNumber>${project.artifactId}-${loaded.timestamp}</buildNumber>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

With this setup:

- whenever you build in the `staging` branch, the current timestamp will be written to `timestamp.txt`.
- when you merge the `staging` branch to the `prod` branch and build using `the` prod profile, it will use the timestamp from `timestamp.txt` as the `buildNumber`.

Do commit the `timestamp.txt` file to your repository after each `staging` build so that it is available during the `prod` build after a merge. That ensures that the artifact name remains consistent across both branches after the merge.